# A Batch Script that runs depending on the Windows edition

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-10

I am looking for a batch that will allow me to run or not depending on the edition of Windows. It will run on all editions of Windows 10 except Home (or Core) and S. For the moment I have successfully filtered according to the build but it is not enough.

I also looked at the registry key EditionID in : `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion` and `wmic os get caption` but being a beginner in batch I can't integrate it in my .bat

```
FOR /f "tokens=6 delims=[]. " %%i in ('ver') do SET build=%%i
IF %build% LSS 17763 (
COLOR E
ECHO.===============================================================================
ECHO.           ALERT - Not compatible with previous versions ... the RS5
ECHO.===============================================================================
ECHO.
PAUSE
GOTO :EOF
)
```

Comment: If you can't check for the presence of certain keywords in the output of the wmic command, then you could run the command and output it to a file using '>'. Then you could try and check that file for keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use this at the beginning of your batch file:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set /A "SKU=OSV=0"
For /F "EOL=O Tokens=1,2 Delims=. " %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe
 OS Where "Version>10" Get OperatingSystemSKU^, Version 2^>NUL'
) Do Set /A "SKU=%%G, OSV=%%H" 2>NUL
If Not %OSV% Equ 10 GoTo :EOF
For %%G In (98 99 100 101 123 125 126 129 130 131) Do If %%G Equ %SKU% GoTo :EOF
Rem Your code goes here
```

The idea is to end the script if the detected OS is not Windows 10, and if the Windows 10 Edition is any one of the following:

| Edition Identifier | SKU | Operating System Definition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CoreN | 98 | Windows 10 Home N |
| CoreCountrySpecific | 99 | Windows 10 Home China |
| CoreSingleLanguage | 100 | Windows 10 Home single language |
| Core | 101 | Windows 10 Home |
| IoTUAP | 123 | Windows 10 IoT Core |
| EnterpriseS | 125 | Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB |
| EnterpriseSN | 126 | Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB N |
| EnterpriseSEval | 129 | Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB Evaluation |
| EnterpriseSNEval | 130 | Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB N Evaluation |
| IoTUAPCommercial | 131 | Windows 10 IoT Core Commercial |

*You can obviously add or remove SKU's within the parentheses on line `8` as required.*

Comment: Merci ;) , it works great, you're a genius. Would you have a link to look up the "SKU" in decimal like in your table, because the only thing I found is this: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getproductinfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN) but you have to convert them and it is dated 2018 (some are missing).

Comment: TBH, I don't @saitama. I use a personal list, currently 113 items, which I've created myself over many years of PC repair and installation. _Of those, I think that 29 are possible Windows 10 editions._